# Is it possible to make existing icon lighter on hover

Tags: qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

For example I've `QToolButton` with custom icon

Can I make this icon lighter on hover using `QToolButton:hover` qss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try below options:

**option 1:**

Try `PaletteRole` property type

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#paletterole

As you require for hovering,

```
QToolButton:hover { color: palette(light); }
```

**option 2:**

Create a different image with lighter view Icon.

And set the background when you `hover` on it.

```
QToolButton:hover { background: url("LighterView.png") ; }
```

Comment: seems like only affects text

Comment: second method works but image is bigger than button and doesn't fit it

Comment: border-image works but not when I have text with icon ... not sure how to deal in case of text with icon

Comment: In the palette role (in the link in my answer), there are different options for text, so we may need to OR them, I guess... something like QToolButton:hover { color: palette(light|text ); } or  QToolButton:hover { color: palette(light|button-text ); }